# Flutter autofill login

Tags: flutter, authentication, autofill

I found several questions similar to this but nothing has worked.
I probably didn't get the basics of the autofill functions.

I'm testing my code on an iPhone 11 Pro (physical device). I would like this to work also on Android, but I currently do not have any physical device to test with, just the simulators.

I have a simple login form with Email and Password fields:

```
TextFormField(keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
textInputAction: TextInputAction.next), 

TextFormField(obscureText: true,
autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password],
onEditingComplete: () => TextInput.finishAutofillContext()),
```

Once the data has been inserted, I save them in two variables (`_email` and `_password`), and when the submit button is pressed I check them with `FirebaseAuth`. The login process is working correctly.

I would like to save these credentials and remember them on the following login.
I save them on `secure_storage`, since I read somewhere that this saves them on iOS Keychain... but is not doing anything.

I do not get asked to save the credentials when I submit the form. When I click on the fields for filling them, the keyboard suggests me to open "Passwords", but there is no instance related to my app.

I read some threads but I do not understand what should I do. It seems that it should be working automatically, but is not the case.

There are some settings I need to check?
Do I need to import some libraries?

Please be as clear as possible, is my first Flutter app.
Thanks.

Comment: I need this for flutter web too, please if somebody can help

Answer (score 6):

Wrap your TextFormFields with `AutofillGroup` to let the user save them with a password manager.

```
AutofillGroup(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      ),
      TextFormField(
        obscureText: true,
        autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password],
        onEditingComplete: () =>
          TextInput.finishAutofillContext(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

If you want the app to handle the autofill you need to get the credentials from `secure_storage` and insert the values into the form.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry it took so long to review your answer. I paused my project. I tried your solution now... but it doesn't seem to work. I was wondering: do you have a Form object outside the AutofillGroup? And what about the "submit" function? Maybe I am doing something wrong there..

Answer (score 3):

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AutofillGroup(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(controller: username, autofillHints: [AutofillHints.username]),
          TextField(controller: newPassword, autofillHints: [AutofillHints.newPassword]),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your code worked fine in Android, but the credential was not saved on my iOS device. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @DevalJoshi check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76897229/9678050

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any additional packages for generating or saving credentials to iOS keychain but you have to setup [associated domains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains) for your app. For a quick guide how to setup associated domains for autofill see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77660690/20320785).

After setting up associated domains you just have to wrap your input fields with `AutofillGroup`.

```
AutofillGroup(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      TextFormField(
        autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Email',
          labelText: 'Email',
      ),
      TextFormField(
        autofillHints: [AutofillHints.newPassword],
        keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Password',
          labelText: 'Password',
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```