# Flutter Autofill for IOS Associated Domains

Tags: ios, flutter, autofill

I'm having trouble fully understanding the autofill feature. The documentation on the Flutter website talks about the additional setup required for IOS.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/autofillHints.html

> Set up your iOS app's associated domains.

The documentation talks about posting the file on a trusted site. The procedure itself, and adding it to Xcode seems clear to me. What I have a problem with is what exactly this file should look like.

Of course, I already have the whole thing in dart fully written and configured. It works very well on Android.

Can anyone suggest what this file should look like?

````
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app", "ABCDE12345.com.example.app2" ],
             "components": [
               {
                  "#": "no_universal_links",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/buy/*",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /buy/"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/help/website/*",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/website/ and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/help/*",
                  "?": { "articleNumber": "????" },
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/ and which has a query item with name 'articleNumber' and a value of exactly 4 characters"
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app" ]
   },

    "appclips": {
        "apps": ["ABCED12345.com.example.MyApp.Clip"]
    }
}```
````

Comment: Is your problem resolved? I'm having the same problem with autofill, could you please help me and suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The associated domains setup is only necessary if you want to autofill credentials (autofill email/username, autogenerate keychain password, save credentials to keychain and autofill next time). Autofilling phonenumber etc. should work without associated domains.

If you only need credentials autofill this file will work:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [],
                "components": []
            }
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "ABCDE12345.com.example.app",
            "ABCDE12345.com.example.app.dev"
        ]
    },
    "appclips": {
        "apps": []
    }
}
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains), this file has to be available at

`https://yourdomainwithoutredirects.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

After publishing the association file, open your app in xcode, select the *Signing & Capabilities* tab and add the following associated domains entry:

`webcredentials:yourdomainwithoutredirects.com`

When the app is installed for the first time, the device tries to load the apple-app-site-association file.

Note that the file is not fetched directly from your web server, but via apples CDN.

> Starting with macOS 11 and iOS 14, apps no longer send requests for apple-app-site-association files directly to your web server. Instead, they send these requests to an Apple-managed content delivery network (CDN) dedicated to associated domains.

You can check if your file is already available via CDN by visiting:

`https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/yourdomainwithoutredirects.com`

If you want to skip CDN, change your associated domain entry in xcode to:

`webcredentials:yourdomainwithoutredirects.com?mode=developer`

Now wrap your input widget with AutofillGroup, add autofillHints and keyboardType if necessary:

```
AutofillGroup(
  child: TextFormField(
    autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Email',
      labelText: 'Email'
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```