# Autofill not working on iOS but works on Android in Flutter Form with AutofillGroup

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented a Flutter form with an AutofillGroup containing TextFormFields for username and password. The autofill functionality works flawlessly on Android, but on iOS, it doesn't trigger the autofill suggestions. Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
  Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: AutofillGroup(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          controller: _usernameController,
          autofillHints: [AutofillHints.username],
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Username',
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: _passwordController,
          autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password],
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Password',
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
              TextInput.finishAutofillContext();
              // Submit form
            }
          },
          child: Text('Submit'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use autofill for credentials on iOS, you have to setup [associated domains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains).

For a quick guide on how to setup assciated domains see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77660690/20320785)